# Windows batch for assigning parameter to a variable

Tags: batch-file, command-line

To the environment set-up I need to pass the for `%aa` parameter to the variable. It seems simple `set myvar=%%d` is not enough. I tried to do some external call to the converter, but I'm not pretty sure how to set-up it. I finished with more a less following solution. But definetly it is not what I expect. I expect to properly echo myvar showing the proper values a, b, c, d one by one, but I could see the last one only.

```
for %%a in (a,b,c,d) do (
  call :extractvar myvar %%a
  echo %myvar%
)

:extractvar <resvar> <invar> (
  set "%1"
  exit /b
)
```

Comment: two issues: [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) and in the subroutine, it should be `set "%1=%2"` (and a missing `goto :eof` to prevent falling into the subroutine after the `for`loop ends, but I guess you are aware of that)

Comment: simplest solution: `for %%a in (a,b,c,d) do echo %%a`. If you need the variable for some reason: `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, `for %%a in (a,b,c,d) do (`, `set "myvar=%%a"`, `echo !myvar!`, `)`